# Bundle styles in Vue Plugin without Component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, plugins, vuejs2

### My Question

Before reading further, by 'without component', I mean that my plugin does not require a component as there is no template, it is simply a custom Vue Directive that serves as a wrapper to a `class`. However, that does not mean that I am not willing to use a component in order to include the necessary styles if this cannot be avoided...

Consider the following plugin (**proposed** file structure):

```
src
│   index.js
│   SomeClass.js    
│
└───sass // (not sure about this)
    │   core.scss
```

- `index.js` installs the Vue plugin and defines a custom directive that calls certain methods on the `SomeClass` class
- `SomeClass.js` provides all required functionality
- `sass/core.scss` provides any necessary styles required for the plugin

My question, quite simply, is how do I include the `core.scss` file when the Vue plugin is installed? Or, what would be a better file structure, thus way to include the styles required for the plugin?

Ideally, I would like to avoid using a template as there is no HTML inserted, my plugin simply adds styles to already defined elements in the DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone stumbling upon this, the solution was extremely easy... I simply placed the following at the top of my `index.js`:

```
import './sass/_core.scss';
```

I wasn't aware that you could import CSS/SASS files directly into Javascript files...